# How to store html with inline style in database and prevent XSS

Tags: php, html, laravel, xss

I need to store html in database to provide user with rich text editing functionality, but at the same time I wish to prevent any possible xss attacks. Is there something that I can use that would remove any harmful javascript while leaving my other html tags and inline style intact?

I am building my project in laravel 5.4

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try http://htmlpurifier.org/

Comment: Put it as an answer, because it is what I was looking for.